# Como colocar os xticks iguais aos dessa figura

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

Estou fazendo um curso de Python voltado para finanças. Daí em um exercício é pedido para plotar um gráfico usando os DataFrames. Até aí tudo bem, consegui fazer tudo certo, entretanto meus xticks não batem com os do resultado!

Eu tenho que obter basicamente isso:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas estou obtendo isso aqui: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém saberia me explicar como obter os mesmos xticks que o cidadão?

Obs.: São séries temporais em Pandas que devem ser plotadas ford,tesla e gm são DataFrames e estou plotando a coluna 'Open' deste dataframe. Os indices dos DataFrames são todos os mesmos, datas de 2012-01-01 até 2017-01-01.

obs2.: O código usado pelo prof. foi o seguinte:

```
tesla['Open'].plot(label='Tesla',figsize=(16,8),title='Open Price')
gm['Open'].plot(label='GM')
ford['Open'].plot(label='Ford')
plt.legend()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá!

Primeiramente, existem diversas formas diferentes para resolver esses problemas de customização. Abaixo é uma forma que eu costuma utilizar e me parece mais legível.

Nesse caso, defini um `axis` onde todas os plots e customizações serão setados:

```
# Definição do axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)

# Note que agora é necessário definir o axis que cada plot será exibido
tesla['Open'].plot(ax = ax, label = "Tesla", figsize = (16,8), title = "Open Price")
gm['Open'].plot(ax = ax, label = "GM")
ford['Open'].plot(ax = ax, label = "Ford")
```

Pela imagem de sua pergunta, me parece que o `xticks` foi separado em intervalos de 6 meses. Considerando que os índices de todos os DataFrames são os mesmos, é necessário definir a posição onde cada `xtick` vai aparecer e depois formatar para que apareça `2016-07`, por exemplo.

```
# Cria um vetor com as datas a cada 6 meses
# O parâmetro freq pode receber diversas frequências diferentes (Y, m, d, ...)
positions = pd.date_range(tesla.index[0], tesla.index[-1], freq='6m')

# Formata os labels
labels = positions.strftime('%Y-%m')
```

Agora setamos as datas formatadas no eixo das abscissas

```
# Remove localizadores desnecessários no eixo x
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(plt.NullLocator())

# Seta a posição das datas
ax.set_xticks(positions[1:])
# Seta os labels nas devidas posições
ax.set_xticklabels(labels[1:])
```

Para inclinar os labels, basta adicionar uma rotação ao `xticks` com o comando `plt.xticks(rotation = angle)`, onde o `angle` é o ângulo de rotação em graus dos xticks em relação ao eixo das abscissas.

```
plt.xticks(rotation = 30)
```

Por último, configuramos o gráfico para ficar ajustado à imagem

```
plt.autoscale(axis = 'x', tight=True)
```

Código completo:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)

tesla['Open'].plot(ax = ax, label = "Tesla", figsize = (16,8), title = "Open Price")
gm['Open'].plot(ax = ax, label = "GM")
ford['Open'].plot(ax = ax, label = "Ford")

positions = pd.date_range(tesla.index[0], tesla.index[-1], freq='6m')
labels = positions.strftime('%Y-%m')

ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(plt.NullLocator())
ax.set_xticks(positions[1:])
ax.set_xticklabels(labels[1:])

plt.xticks(rotation = 30)

plt.legend()
plt.autoscale(axis = 'x', tight=True)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Referências:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44078409/matplotlib-semi-log-plot-minor-tick-marks-are-gone-when-range-is-large

https://scentellegher.github.io/programming/2017/05/24/pandas-bar-plot-with-formatted-dates.html